# unix shell tips to assign boolean value to variable from a test

Tags: shell, ksh

code to show the request in context (unix ksh currently):

```
r=$( [ -z "foo" ] && echo true || echo false )
```

is there a better, simplerway to assign `r` with true or false something like `r=$( [ -z "foo" ])`  (that seems to give an empty value) or `r=[ -z "foo" ]` that failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[ ... ]` construct (or the equivalent `test ...`) returns a completion code of 0 for true or 1 for false, but it never generates any output, so `$( [ ... ] )` always returns an empty string. The returned completion code is in `$?`, so `r` can be set to 0 or 1 by:

```
[ -z "foo" ]; r=$?
```

If you want the text values `true` and `false` in `r` (as opposed to 0 and 1), then your expression is basically correct, but the following is a bit simpler:

```
[ -z "foo" ] && r=true || r=false
```

Comment: basically that's what i do i my script. The echo is there because it assign a generic variable at en upper level in original script. i forget to use the $? as input, thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

Not the case here :

```
$ b=false
$ r=$b
$ echo $r
false
$
```

Comment: oops, sorry for the purpose i assign the value but it's the result of a test; I adapt the request.